# Advanced `data.table` working fine when run in chunk but error when `knit2html`

Tags: r, data.table, r-markdown, knitr

I tried to refer to below links to use `data.table` package to calculate `mape`,`smape`,`mse`,`rmse`, its working fine with below codes when run in chunk but become error when `knit2html`. Somebody shade me a light?

- https://tysonbarrett.com/jekyll/update/2019/10/06/datatable_memory
- http://brooksandrew.github.io/simpleblog/articles/advanced-data-table

```
## https://tysonbarrett.com/jekyll/update/2019/10/06/datatable_memory
## http://brooksandrew.github.io/simpleblog/articles/advanced-data-table
require('DescTools')
require('data.table')

setorder(seasonal_m1, index)

open.accr <- seasonal_m1[, {
  open = open
  open.Point.Forecast = open.Point.Forecast
  .SD[, .(.N, open.mape = MAPE(open, open.Point.Forecast), 
          open.smape = SMAPE(open, open.Point.Forecast), 
          open.mse = MSE(open, open.Point.Forecast), 
          open.rmse = RMSE(open, open.Point.Forecast)), 
      by={index=as_date(index)}]}, 
  by=.(Model, Period)]
```

**Error :**

```
Error in `[.tbl_df`(seasonal_m1, , { : 
  object 'open.Point.Forecast' not found
Calls: <Anonymous> ... withCallingHandlers -> withVisible -> eval -> eval -> [ -> [.tbl_df
Execution halted
```

[image: error knit2html]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
seasonal_m1 <- data.table(seasonal_m1)
setorder(seasonal_m1, index)
```

solved, need to convert seasonal_m1 to a data.table format. https://github.com/yihui/knitr/issues/1941#issuecomment-759275616